# How can I bypass CORS security in a browser?

Tags: javascript, php, html, security, cors

I have a Javascript application running in a browser, and I want to access some data sitting in a server that can't enable CORS.
It's not a testing application, is meant for the end-user, even if a little techy one.

I considered:

- PHP Proxy: Not appropriate. Server on the other side make decision about IP geolocation.
- Java/SilverLight: Unfortunately my #1 target is Chrome
- JSON: Not available

What are my options?

**Please notice that I'm not trying to make any malicious application: if the user need to approve or allow me to make this request is totally fine.**

Comment: In case if it is for testing you can try the `Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *` chrome extension - (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en) or even the `CORS-Toggle` available here => https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cors-toggle/omcncfnpmcabckcddookmnajignpffnh?hl=en

Comment: Why is a proxy not an option? You can forward the relevant headers (such as X-Forwarded-For) to the end server

Comment: @remdevtec Interesting option, even if I don't think is suited for what I'm trying to do (I don't have the full control of the other server)

Comment: If your application sends this http header: Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *, then it should allow the browser to make an ajax request to another domain

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to do exactly what the Same Origin Policy is designed to prevent (and what CORS is designed to allow the *server* to permit).

Your options are:

- Find a way to work with whomever controls the server
- Get the users to download and install software which isn't subject to the Same Origin Policy (such as a stand-alone application or a browser extension).

Answer (score 1):

You need to ask your users to install chrome extension to overcome CORS. I used to use it while developing ionic apps and testing on chrome

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cors-toggle/omcncfnpmcabckcddookmnajignpffnh?hl=en